# Modifying mutableList value outside of composable not saving one parameter, but saving other

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, state

I have an object, Day, with 2 required parameters; An id (Int) which is generated in another composable (which is transferring the value correctly), and a values parameter which is a list of Doubles (that are not being transferred).

I don't understand why the id of each object is being modified correctly, but the values are not. What is even more strange to me is that if I create a variable of the Day type and print the values that are coming from the composable doing the calculations, it does contain the correct values.

However, when I try to add each day to a mutableList of Days, each day only contains the correct id, and an empty list of values.

Here is the day class

```
data class Day(
    val id: Int = 0,
    val values: List<Double> = emptyList<Double>(),
    val dayOfWeek: Int? = null
)
```

this is how I've declared the function

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(days: List<Day>,
             onAddDay: (Day) -> Unit) {

var test = Day(id = dayCounter.toInt()
                    , dailyvalues)

// then I call the onAddDay function with the test Day variable
onAddDay(test)
```

in my main activity

```
var days = remember { mutableListOf<Day>() }

Greeting(days,
                        onAddDay = {
                            val test = Day(id = it.id, values = it.values)
                            if (test.values.isNotEmpty()) {
                                days.add(test)
                            }
                            Log.d("Final", test.toString())
                        }
                    )
                    Log.d("Final", days.toString())
                }
```

here is the output I get from Log.d

the first part is for each test object, which do indeed hold the correct information for both "id" and "values".

```
Day(id=30, values=[8.925, 8.86, 8.79, 8.72], dayOfWeek=null)
Day(id=29, values=[8.65, 8.58, 8.51, 8.44], dayOfWeek=null)
....
Day(id=0, values=[0.53, 0.46, 0.39, 0.32], dayOfWeek=null)
```

and then the next part for the list of days, which somehow loses the data for "values", yet holds the correct data for "id".

```
[Day(id=30, values=[], dayOfWeek=null), Day(id=29, values=[], dayOfWeek=null), .... Day(id=0, values=[], dayOfWeek=null)]
```

I have tried modifying the day class, using mutableList and mutablestateof but I just don't understand why the id's are being modified in the days variable but not the values.

Comment: Where is the code that adds/creates the values?

Comment: @TheLibrarian It's in the Greeting function, and it appears to be working correctly. But when I try to add each test day variable to the list of days, somehow it erases the values.

`onAddDay = { val test = Day(id = it.id, values = it.values)
                            if (test.values.isNotEmpty()) { days.add(test) }
                            Log.d("Final", test.toString())`

this last line shows that the test days object holds the correct id but and the correct value. But for some reason the values won't get saved to the days list

Comment: Yeah, I got that part but where do you create dailyvalues?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is this:

```
val test = Day(id = it.id, values = it.values)
if (test.values.isNotEmpty()) {
  days.add(test)
}
Log.d("Final", test.toString())
...
Log.d("Final", days.toString())
```

If `it.values` is empty, then `test` will never be added to `days`, and it will be empty like you are seeing.

Isn't the `values` list always empty at the start?

You could potentially investigate the issue more thoroughly if you change your `Day` to not have the emptyList as a default value.

i.e.

```
data class Day(
    val id: Int = 0,
    val values: List<Double>,  // This
    val dayOfWeek: Int? = null
)
```

I think that'll help you understand where you think its being set and where it is actually being set.

Answer (score 0):

Your `days` variable in your Composable is a MutableList. It’s not State so it won’t trigger recompositions when you change the contents. Change it to State like this:

```
var days = remember { mutableStateListOf<Day>() }
```

Beyond that, if you are reusing list instances when you create new Day instances/copies, that will also cause problems because Compose needs to be able to compare the old and new values to see what has changed. If you reuse a list, the old value is going to contain the same list as the new value so no change can be detected. There’s no longer a record of the previous contents to compare to.